# Please explain this Validation Rule

Tags: apex, validation-rule, standard-objects

Can anybody explain me what does this validation rule does. This is on standard object Account.

```
AND(
OR(
RecordType.Name=="Subcontractor"
),
OR(
ISNEW(), 
ISCHANGED(RecordTypeId)
),
NOT($Setup.VRuleSettings__c.HasSubsRTAccess__c )
)
```

Comment: See documentation on the [$Setup](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_setup.htm) Global Variable.

Comment: you can also use c-style && and || operators. much clearer imo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following points **all** have to resolve to *true* for the validation rule to trigger an error:

- Record Type name must be Subcontractor
- Record must be newly created **or** the Record Type must have been changed
- The Custom Setting HasSubsRTAccess__c in VRuleSettings__c must be false for this User (this can be User, Profile or Organization specific)

Answer (score 1):

I'd format it like this.  It makes what it does clearer.

```
AND( OR(RecordType.Name=="Subcontractor"),
OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED(RecordTypeId)),
NOT($Setup.VRuleSettings__c.HasSubsRTAccess__c )
)
```

This is True if the

```
((record type is subcontractor) AND
(the record is a new one OR the record type ID has changed)) AND
( Not ...HasSubsRtAccess__c is True)
```

I'm not sure what that last condition means, but if it isn't true, the whole expression will be false. So,  ...HasSubsRtAccess__c must be false (because of the NOT) for the whole condition to be True.

Comment: Its an `AND` between `record type is subcontractor` and `the record is a new one OR the record type ID has changed` not and `OR`.

Comment: corrected the logic.  I was thrown by the OR with just one argument